# When does 'end' or 'close' get called on tls.connect

Tags: node.js

For examples like this:
https://bravenewmethod.com/2011/02/21/node-js-tls-client-example/

Or in my own code:

```
client = tls.connect(port, host, tlsOptions, function() {
                                    
}

client.on('end', function(data) {

}
```

When do these lifecycle methods get actually called?  In the documentation, https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html, I don't see anything about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to be looking in the doc for the Net module for a TCP socket which a TLS socket inherits from.  `tls.TLSSocket` is a subclass of [`net.Socket`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket).  This is a common issue with documentation for a class hierarchy where you don't realize that lots of things are documented in the base class documentation.  In [that doc](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_end), it says this for the `end` event:

> Emitted when the other end of the socket sends a FIN packet, thus
>   ending the readable side of the socket.
>
> By default (allowHalfOpen is false) the socket will send a FIN packet
>   back and destroy its file descriptor once it has written out its
>   pending write queue. However, if allowHalfOpen is set to true, the
>   socket will not automatically end() its writable side, allowing the
>   user to write arbitrary amounts of data. The user must call end()
>   explicitly to close the connection (i.e. sending a FIN packet back).

For the `close` event, [that same doc](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_close_1) says this:

> Emitted once the socket is fully closed. The argument had_error is a
>   boolean which says if the socket was closed due to a transmission
>   error.

This means that the `close` event comes after the `end` event since the socket may be still at least partially open when the `end` event is received.

---

So, you will get `end` when the other side has told you it is no longer accepting data (receipt of FIN packet) and you will get `close` when the socket is now completely closed.

Answer (score 0):

The `tls.TLSSocket` class is an instance of the `net.Socket` class.  You can find additional information about the events and methods it has in that documentation (https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket). Most likely, `net.Socket#end` if I had to guess.